# stack overflow error - maybe an infinite loop

Tags: java

please excuse my ignorance as I am very new to programming. I'm currently trying to build a calculator project in which I need to have one Jframe class and a Java class. The jframe contains all the interface and the bulk of the calculation is on the java class. What I did is I created a method on the Java class and tried to call it on the Jframe class.

Thanks in advance cheers!
Here's the code for the Java Class

```
public class Calculations extends cpCalcFrame {

    public double mathoperations()
    {
        String answer;
        secNum = Double.parseDouble(txtOutput.getText());
        switch (operation)
      {
         case "+":
             if(secNum == 0)
             {
                 msgMessage.showMessageDialog(this, "ERROR: Cannot add by zero", "Error Message", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             }
             else
             {
            result= firstNum + secNum;
            answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
            txtOutput.setText(answer);
            break;
             }

         case "-":
             if(secNum == 0)
             {
                 msgMessage.showMessageDialog(this, "ERROR: Cannot subtract by zero", "Error Message", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             }
             else
             {
            result= firstNum - secNum;
            answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
            txtOutput.setText(answer);           
            break;
             }

    case "*":
            if(secNum == 0)
             {
                 msgMessage.showMessageDialog(this, "ERROR: Cannot multiply by zero", "Error Message", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             }
             else
             {
            result= firstNum * secNum;
            answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
            txtOutput.setText(answer);
            break;
             }

         case "/":
             if(secNum == 0)
             {
                 msgMessage.showMessageDialog(this, "ERROR: Cannot divide by zero", "Error Message", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             }
             else
             {
            result= firstNum / secNum;
            answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
            txtOutput.setText(answer);

            break;
             }

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and here's my Jframe class code:

```
public class cpCalcFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public double firstNum;
    public double secNum;
    public double result;
    public String operation;
    **Calculations b = new Calculations();**
    /**
     * Creates new form cpCalcFrame
     */
    public cpCalcFrame() {
        initComponents();
        this.setSize(330, 320);
    }          

    private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn1.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn2.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btn3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn3.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btn4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn4.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btn5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn5.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btn6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn6.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btn7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn7.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btn8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn8.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btn9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn9.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btn0ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btn0.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                    

    private void btndecActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        String input;
        input = txtOutput.getText() + btndec.getText();
        txtOutput.setText(input);
    }                                      

    private void btnCAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        txtOutput.setText("");
        firstNum = 0;
        secNum = 0;
    }                                     

    private void btnCEActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        txtOutput.setText("");
    }                                     

    private void btnmultActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        firstNum = Double.parseDouble(txtOutput.getText());
        txtOutput.setText("");
        operation = "*";
    }                                       

    private void btndivActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        firstNum = Double.parseDouble(txtOutput.getText());
        txtOutput.setText("");
        operation = "/";
    }                                      

    private void btnaddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        firstNum = Double.parseDouble(txtOutput.getText());
        txtOutput.setText("");
        operation = "+";
    }                                      

    private void btnminActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        firstNum = Double.parseDouble(txtOutput.getText());
        txtOutput.setText("");
        operation = "-";
    }                                      

    **private void btnequalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        b.mathoperations();**
    }                                        

    private void btnexclam1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if (txtOutput.getText().length() > 0) {
        txtOutput.setText(txtOutput.getText().substring(0, txtOutput.getText().length() - 1));
}
    }
```

Comment: the method is called on the equals button

Comment: please, post **only** relevant code parts if you expect an answer....

Comment: If you have a Stack Overflow error you should report it as a bug on Meta...

Comment: @musefan What? Why would this go on meta?

Comment: @CaffeineToCode: Sorry, my mistake, im from a parallel universe and I keep forgetting jokes aren't a thing over here. I would move back but the bus fair is too much

Comment: @musefan Oh. Nvm. I get it. Use some emoticons or something to make it more obvious it is indeed a joke.

Comment: You should also post the error you get and where is the line that the error is referring (in your code).

Comment: I'm getting this error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
 at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
 
 at cpcalc.cpCalcFrame.<init>(cpCalcFrame.java:28)
 at cpcalc.Calculations.<init>(Calculations.java:12)
 at cpcalc.cpCalcFrame.<init>(cpCalcFrame.java:24)
 at cpcalc.Calculations.<init>(Calculations.java:12)
 at cpcalc.cpCalcFrame.<init>(cpCalcFrame.java:24)
 at cpcalc.Calculations.<init>(Calculations.java:12)

Comment: @JpSison: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32610221/edit) to include the error, and as only you have access to the line numbers. Highlight the relevant line of code or us

Comment: @musefan I'm sorry to be a nuisance but I'm a bit confused how this works. All I know that the error when I try to run is pointing at line 24 of the jframe class(Calculations b = new Calculations();) and line 12 of the Java class (public class Calculations extends cpCalcFrame). Hope this helps

Comment: Where is `txtOutput` defined?

Comment: It's on the JFrame class cpCalc

Answer (score 0):

`Calculations` is a subclass of `cpCalcFrame`, and `cpCalcFrame` has a field which is initialized with a **new** `Calculations` object:

```
Calculations b = new Calculations();
```

So, when you first call `new Calculations()` somewhere else, it
will initialize the super class, which calls `new Calculations()`, which
will initialize the super class, which calls `new Calculations()`, which
will initialize the super class, which calls `new Calculations()`, which
will initialize the super class, which calls `new Calculations()`, which
will initialize the super class, which calls `new Calculations()`, which
will initialize the super class, which calls `new Calculations()`, which
will throw `StackOverflowError`.

**Solution:** Remove the `extends cpCalcFrame` from `Calculations` and pass in any needed values on the `mathoperations()` method.

Comment: I'm still confused, do I need to add some codes to stop the loop?

Comment: You need to change some code, which means add some and remove some. Start where I said: *Remove* `extends cpCalcFrame` from class `Calculations`, then *add* parameters to `mathoperations()`.

Comment: if I remove the extends cpCalcFrame from Calculations I would be getting more errors(cannot find symbol )as the txtOutput textfield is on the jframe class even if I set the properties>code>variable modifiers>public.